# How do I change text colour in this css code?

Tags: css

I have a simple header with some menu items:

```
<div id="header">
<ul id="menu">
<li class="item">
<a class='loginlinks' href='/signup'>Sign Up</a>
<a class='loginlinks' href='/login'>Log In</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to change the Sign Up and Log In text colour to white using the code below but it's having no effect...the text keeps inheriting the global text colour of red.

```
.loginlinks a {
color: white;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** I see my error, however even changing css to **a.loginlinks** did not do the trick.

**RESOLVED** All correct answers, I selected the reference to firebug as that ultimately helped me identify the problem. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice is to use color code (hex), not the name.

```
a.loginlinks {
color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

because assigning color by color name is now deprecated.

#### [working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6rFFq/)

**note:** if you still have the problem then try to debug with firebug, it may be that some other property is inherited

### Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CSS-TECHS/#style-color-contrast

Comment: @lonesomeday i gave the links too

Comment: Good stuff, +1. It's interesting that this isn't mentioned in [a 10-year-younger document on CSS color](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#html4).

Comment: OK - resolved. Using firebug allowed me to see where the red colour was being inherited from. Thanks for the help. Question: I thought specifying DOM element specific css would override any css that came before in the css...is this not the case?

Comment: [That link](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CSS-TECHS/#style-color-contrast) was written in 2000. In CSS3 they decided that using color names in CSS is cool with them.

Answer (score 4):

That says "`a` tags within elements of the `loginlinks` class".  You want "`a` tags that have the `loginlinks` class":

```
a.loginlinks {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :)

```
a.loginlinks {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: you will get more points when you give a more detailed answer. (compare lonesomeday's answer to yours.)

Comment: Thanks, I will try to provide more detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

that's because there are no .`loginlinks a` at your DOM.

In other words, check it again and you'll see that the class `.loginlinks` is attached to the `a`.

So, in order to meke it work, just use this CSS:

```
a.loginlinks {
   color: white;
}
```

EDIT: after reading the OP edit, the solution depends on how the "global" `a` are behing defined.

If the OP is "desperate" he/she can use the `!important` property, whch will override all other definitions.

Like this:

```
a.loginlinks {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change CSS to

```
a.loginlinks {
color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm assuming your condition correctly then it will be solve like this

```
body {background:red;color:red}
#header a {color:yellow}
#header a.loginlinks {color: white }
```

See example here http://jsfiddle.net/pyNEe/